# Multiple subnets or extended network?

Tags: routing, wireless

We have 2 satellite locations which are linked to our main network with "Wireless AP/Outdoor CPE/Network Bridge/Repeater/WIFI Signal Booster & Amplifier" devices.

We can access the internet from each location but we cannot seem to ping/remote to any of the devices connected to each of the locations.

The first device in the chain connects to our network via cable and is assigned an IP address on what it calls it's WAN side. It's LAN side then has a different IP address so I think that each wireless device is creating it's own subnet (they seem to be in 'gateway' mode).
I think it the solution must be something to do with routing but I'm afraid that is where my knowledge is lacking and I'm coming a bit unstuck with it all.

Should we be creating separate subnets at each location or should we extend the original network IP range to each site?

We have DVR's at each location that need to be accessed directly from the main network.

Each device has plenty of modes and options (gateway, bridge, repeater, etc.) but we cannot seem to get them all working the way we would like.

Many thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 2):

Just turn NAT off and the firewall (or open needed ports) on the remote APs, add routes to the remote subnets pointing to the outside interface address of the Router/AP at the remote locations.
Bridging will work but will come with a lot more configuration and opens up more problems from in operation. DHCP over WAN will cause local resources at the remote locations to become unavailable if the main site or the connection goes down. Also DHCP over a wireless WAN link can lead to problems if that link is ever saturated or if it get's affected by weather conditions. Also you'll have to think about where your gateway is going to be. Also those links will now have all layer 2 traffic on it when it wouldn't need to be. I don't know the bandwidth of them or current utilization but this could issues that are easily avoided.

HTH, Let me know if this makes sense or you need clarification.

Comment: Slow down there cowboy! I was with you up until you started talking about WAN's.

Comment: Should I be extending the original network out to each site (repeater mode?) or should I be creating a new subnet at each site? (AP mode I think?)

Comment: Haha sorry, You could just extend the original network, it will work this way. What that whole rant was about is full reliance on a WAN link, you don't want this. Instead I would keep the seperate networks, turn NAT off and open the firewall at the remote sites. Then at the main site put a route in the default gateway to get to those networks. Take a look at this diagram: http://imgur.com/JHjf8HN
Replace your IPs with those and make necessary change to design to fit your environment. Hopefully the visualization clears it up some!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your remote sites are doing NAT which would present the symptoms that you describe.

There are many options to fix this.  A simple solutions would be to set the devices comprising the links into bridge mode, and have a separate VLAN for each link at your main site. The main site would then perform DHCP for the remote sites, and you would have routes to the remote sites.

Comment: I'm not sure this would work because each site is daisy-chained from the previous site. Site 1 --> Site 2 --> Site 3